# $H \odot K$ complete implies $\dim H$ or $\dim K <\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, complete-spaces

Let $H,K$ be non-zero Hilbert spaces. Then the algebraic tensor product $H \odot K$ is an inner product space for the unique inner product determined by
$$\langle h \otimes k, h' \otimes k'\rangle = \langle h, h'\rangle_H \langle k, k' \rangle_K$$

I am trying to prove that $H \odot K$ is a Hilbert space (i.e. $H \odot K$ is complete for the norm induced by this inner product) implies that $\dim H <\infty$ or $\dim K < \infty$.

Let us prove the contrapositive, i.e. so suppose that $H$ and $K$ are both infinite dimensional. How can I show that there is a Cauchy sequence in $H \odot K$ that does not converge?

Comment: The statement is false unless $H \ne 0 \ne K$, so you probably want to assume that. \\ It is clear (when $K \ne 0$) that $H$ infinite dimensional implies $H \otimes K$ infinite dimensional (why $H \odot K$?).  Surely you mean that you want to show that, if $H$ is infinite dimensional, then $H \otimes K$ is not *complete*?  In that case, why not see if you can use the infinite dimensionality of $H$ to manufacture a non-convergent Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the comment. I made some edits. Finding this non-convergent Cauchy sequence is exactly what I can't. Do you have any hints for this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: you rejected my edit that inserted the  `<` missing from the title, and then inserted it yourself.  Why?

Comment: I didn't have a specific sequence in mind, and, in fact, I think that the result is still not true.  If $K$ is 1-dimensional, then $H \otimes K$ is isometric to $H$, so is complete even if $H$ is infinite dimensional; and, more generally, $H \otimes \mathbb C^n$ is isometric to $H^{\oplus n}$, which is complete for $n < \infty$.  Are you sure that you don't mean to prove that $\dim(H)$ *or* $\dim(K)$ is finite?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, when you review you don't see the title so I thought nothing at the post was changed

Comment: Also, you are right I made some edits.

Comment: As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces#Explicit_construction you just need an infinite matrix with finite sum of squares of the entries but not of finite rank; a diagonal one will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to exhibit a non-converging Cauchy sequence in $H\odot K$, but actually proving that it does not
converge is a bit more difficult.  The approach suggested by @Max, although somewhat  sophisticated, is perhaps the easiest
way to pin down all of the details.  Here is a pedestrian way to describe this method.

For each pair of vectors $(x, y)\in H\times K$, consider the bounded linear operator
$$
  T_{x, y}:H\to K
  $$
given by
$$
  T_{x, y}(z) =  \langle x,z\rangle y, \quad\forall z\in H.
  $$
(For simplicity I am assuming that we are working with real vector spaces but this can be fixed in the complex case by
seeing   $T_{x, y}$ as an operator defined on $\bar H$, namely the Hilbert space made out of $H$ by adopting the new scalar
multiplication operation $\lambda \cdot x:= \bar \lambda x$).

It is easy to see that the map
$$
  (x, y)\in H\times K\mapsto   T_{x, y}\in  \mathscr {B}(H,K)
  $$
is bilinear so, by the universal property of (algebraic) tensor products, there exists a unique linear map
$$
  T :H\odot K\to  \mathscr {B}(H,K),
  $$
such that $T (x\otimes y) = T_{x,y}$.
We next claim  that
$$
  \langle T (\xi )x,y\rangle  =  \langle \xi ,x\otimes y\rangle ,
  \tag {1}
  $$
for every $\xi $ in $H\odot K$, $x\in  H$, and $y\in  K$. To prove this write  $\xi =\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\otimes y_i$, and notice that
$$
  \langle T (\xi )x,y\rangle  =
  \sum_{i=1}^n   \langle T_{x_i,y_i}(x),y\rangle  = $$ $$ =
  \sum_{i=1}^n   \langle \langle x_i,x\rangle y_i,y\rangle  =
  \sum_{i=1}^n   \langle x_i,x\rangle \langle y_i,y\rangle  = $$ $$ =
  \sum_{i=1}^n   \langle x_i\otimes y_i,x\otimes y\rangle  =
  \langle \xi ,x\otimes y\rangle,
  $$
proving the claim.

Note that the range of each $T_{x,y}$  is the one-dimensional space spanned by $y$, so $T_{x,y}$ has rank 1.
Furthermore, every $\xi $ in $H\odot K$  may be writen as  $\xi =\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\otimes y_i$, so
$$
  T (\xi ) = \sum_{i=1}^n T_{x_i,y_i},
  $$
so we see that   $T (\xi )$ has rank at most $n$, hence finite, for every $\xi $ in $H\odot K$.

The final contradiction will be achieved by proving that, if $H$ and $K$ are infinite dimensional, and $H\odot K$ is  complete, there exists a vector $\xi $ in $H\odot K$  such that $T (\xi )$ has infinite rank.

Let us therefore assume from now on that $H$ and $K$ are both infinite dimensional, so we may find (necessarily infinite)
orthonormal bases
$\{e_i\}_{i\in  I}$, and $\{f_j\}_{j\in  J}$, for $H$ and $K$ respectively, and it is well known that $\{e_i\otimes f_j\}_{(i, j)\in  I\times J}$ is an
orthonormal basis for $H\otimes K$.

Assuming by contradiction that $H\odot K$ is complete,  observe that  $H\odot K$ coincides with its completion,  so   $H\odot K = H\otimes K$.

Choose infinite subsets $\{i_n:n\in {\mathbb N}\}\subseteq I$, and $\{j_n:n\in {\mathbb N}\}\subseteq J$, and let
$$
  \xi  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  {1\over n^2} (e_{i_n}\otimes f_{j_n}).
  $$
This is well defined because the series is clearly absolutely convergent and we are working in a complete space!

Using (1) we have that
$$
  T (\xi )e_{i_n} =
  \sum_{j\in J} \langle T (\xi )e_{i_n}, f_j\rangle f_j =
  \sum_{j\in J} \langle \xi , e_{i_n}\otimes f_j\rangle f_j =
  \langle \xi , e_{i_n}\otimes f_{j_n}\rangle f_{j_n} =
  {1\over n^2} f_{j_n}.
  $$
This shows that ${1\over n^2} f_{j_n}$ lies in the range of $T (\xi )$, and hence that $T (\xi )$ has infinite rank,  a contradiction.

Comment: Definitely harder than I thought! Many thanks! I will go in detail through it soon!

Comment: You are welcome.  And please fell free to ask for any clarification if needed!

Comment: Thanks! That's very kind of you!